# Can't open a text file in C from which i want to read text as data and write it into an array

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    FILE *ptr;
    ptr = fopen("example.txt", "r");
    if (ptr == NULL){
        printf("File not opened or found");
        return 1;
    }
    
    char str[20];
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), ptr);
    printf("Read text from example.txt is: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to C and i got quite a lot confused about the basic file access logic in C, my first question is why did fgets() function accept **ptr** instead of ***ptr** as the third argument? Why the address of the FILE struct instead of what it references to?
When I run the code i always get the error in the if's body, I'm running a windows machine and can't get my C code to retrieve example.txt using fopen() function. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `printf("File not opened or found");` I suggest `perror("opening example.txt failed");` to get additional information about the error.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry, but you have edited the question to invalidate the anwer given by pmg.... IMHO, this is not the way to show the PO where in the code he is wrong, and has forced him to delete his answer.

Comment: @LuisColorado My edit didn't invalidate anything, I just added inline code markdown to the text. ahailtotheKing added curly braces to the code in edit #2, is that what you're talking about?

Comment: @Barmar My apologies then.

Comment: ahailtotheking, please don't modify a question by correcting a mistake that has been signalled in an answer, as that invalidates the question as responses are just unrelated and dumb.  If you correct the question nobody will learn about your mistake, and probably you will get to a non-understandable question when you do this mistake again and search for help.

Comment: @LuisColorado All i did was to add curly braces to the body of the IF statement for the sake of self-correcting. I took notice of that inconsistency right after i wrote the code, and quickly added braces. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You already had a valid answer when you did.  If you ask a question and correct it to make it appear as no error, then nobody learns, except you.  You had better to add info or to explain something unclear to the people trying to help you, but if you solve your problem editing your question, everything is fine and no problem actually exists.  What's the reason for SO to archive and make it available to next requestors a question that has no errors, and an answer that signals an error that is missing on your original question.  This was the reason for @pmg to eliminate his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard stream function to handle files and such, declared in `<stdio.h>` use pointers to opaque `FILE` structures allocated by the library.  The details of the implementation are kept private to the library, all the program needs are `FILE` pointers returned by `fopen()` or `freopen()` and passed as argument to input and output functions.

The library functions update the `FILE` structure appropriately to implement the buffering scheme and other translation functionalities.  If the `FILE` structure was passed directly, it could not be updated as structures are passed by value in C so the library function would just receive a copy of the structure and any updates would be lost as soon as the function returns.

This method is very general and is used by many programming languages behind the scenes. Java objects are typically passed as pointers to methods. The same for javascript objects and arrays.  Functions receiving object references in C++ basically get pointers that are guaranteed to never be null.  In these circumstances, object property access via the `.` operator are translated as pointer dereferencing with some or no additional runtime checks and lookups.

In your exmaple, you say the file cannot be opened: producing a more informative error message is a good habit to help track such failures. The file cannot be open probably because it is not present in the current directory at run time.

You should also check for potential failure in `fgets()` and close the stream with `fclose()`.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *ptr = fopen("example.txt", "r");
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open example.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    
    char str[100];
    if (fgets(str, sizeof(str), ptr)) {
        printf("Read text from example.txt is: %s\n", str);
    } else {
        printf("Cannot read from example.txt: %s\n", 
               ferror(ptr) ? "read error" : "empty file");
    }
    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The message `File example.txt is empty` might not always be correct. In case of `fgets` returning `NULL` you should call `feof` and/or `ferror` to distinguish between errors and EOF, and in case of errors `errno` may contain additional information.

Comment: @Bodo: while your remark is correct, this check is well beyond the OP's skill level and would introduce the `feof()` function that they should stay away from.

Answer (score 3):

All the stdio functions receive a pointer to the `FILE` struct so they can modify the contents of the structure. If you passed the `FILE` struct itself, they would receive a copy of it, because C passes arguments by value (except for arrays, which are automatically converted to a pointer when used as a function argument), and any changes they made would not persist. This allows the `FILE` struct to keep the state of the open stream.

If `fopen()` isn't working, it's probably because the file is not in the correct folder. Relative pathnames are interpreted based on your working directory, not the directory containing the program.